# Ionic collection-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework, angular-material

I used collection-repeat with md-grid-tile below,

```
    <md-grid-tile collection-repeat="record in records" md-rowspan="1"
 md-colspan="1" md-colspan-sm="1" >
<!--- Rest of code --->
</md-grid-tile>
```

but when I run this, it will display error like this in console.

> Error: collection-repeat tried to compute the height of repeated elements "record in records", but was unable to. Please provide the "item-height" attribute

Is there any way to fix this issue??

Comment: well the error seems quite clear and specific. Have you tried setting `item-height`?

Comment: You should read the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) of `collection-repeat`.

Comment: Yes, i didn't set because i need, it to get height and width itself from   collection-repeat

Answer (score 2):

`collection-repeat` works on `item-height` and `item-width`. When these are not provided, it assumes that all the elements in collection will have same height as the first element. When ionic is not able to calculate that, it looks for item-height attribute in your collection repeat element.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate that height and width dynamically

Comment: Not yet. Maybe look into the docs. They overhauled collection-repeat in the recent update of ionic. (1.0.0)